# error pointer: is it okay to reserve random data to be used as error pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, error-handling

I have a situation where pointer returning function can return an address of structure or a NULL pointer. Both cases are possible when the function has no errors. There is still a possibility for error but I cant signal it with NULL pointer. So, is it a possible or a good practice to define some random global data (ed. int or double) and use the address of that to indicate error?

```
int error_variable;

func1(){
    if(func2() != &error_variable) 
    ...
}

pointer *func2(){
    ... 
    /**return some address or NULL in success,
    &error_variable otherwise*/
}
```

I know that its possible to set up system like errno, but this form would shorten the code and keep it readable. There is lots of functions like func2 with different return value types so should the &error_variable be converted to void * and does it certainly work?

Comment: I don' understand why you want to use the address of the global pointer, why don't set the value? I mean, you return the pointer and check its value.

Comment: Why did you make `NULL` a valid pointer? The whole point of it is to be invalid so you can check. I don't see why it should return `NULL` when there is no error. Perhaps you should explain more about that. I see maintainabilty problems with your approach, not too bad but not good.

Comment: @iharob The general idea is that the function uses 2 exceptional return values `NULL` and something else.

Comment: The point was that I only use the **address** of that global variable because the address can not be same as any correct return value. It does not matter what is inside the error address. Not sure if I understood your commet (did you understood my question) @terencehill

Comment: I did understand your question, you should use the global or a static variable for the opposite and leave `NULL` alone. Something like `struct MyStruct *MyStructNull = SOME_ADDRESS;`. Or, pass a pointer to the pointer and return an integer indicating the error status of the function which is a very well known technique widely implemented everywhere.

Comment: The return value is for nonterminal in cfl. Those nonterminals can be some sentences or epsilons. In this case NULL is for epsilon. @iharob

Comment: You should learn how python defineds `None` in their c implementation. Maybe that will take you in the right path.

Comment: I see, you think that the address can be used as the error code because the function, if behaves correctly , will never return such a value. In my opinion you should re-think your function to return a reasonable error value but maybe you are in a situation in which this can be a valid option.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is it a possible or a good practice to define some random ...

Using a random value for a pointer leads to undefined behavior.

> So, is it a possible or a good practice to define some <strike>random</strike> global data (ed. int or double) and use the address of that to indicate error?

Using a pointer to a global variable is a good alternative -  ensure it is a matching type.

```
foo error_variable;

foo *func2() {
  ...
  return &error_variable
  }

func1() {
  if(func2() != &error_variable) 
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have more functions with different return value type that should work with that variable. Can I just convert them to a void before checking or do I need one error pointer for each type?

Comment: @happytomato Since it is an issue to have `void error_variable;`, Code could use `void * error_variable_v`and simply return/compare against `error_variable_v` rather than `&error_variable`.  This could be preferable to prevent code from attempting `error_variable.some_field` should `foo` be a `struct`.  The best answer depends of larger coding goals not posted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not return your pointer via an out-param and then use the return value for an error code? I think that's the cleanest approach.

```
func1(){
    pointer *result;
    if(func2(&result) == 0) {
       if (result != NULL) {
           ...
       } else {
           ...
       } 
    }
}

int func2(pointer **result){
    ... 
    /* success case */
    *result = null_or_not ? NULL : some_pointer;
    return 0;

    /* error case */
    return error_code;
    /* in this case result could be left untouched or set to NULL.
       up to you to define the interface there. */
}
```